# How to change Android studio JRE default path?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Program Files\Android\android studio\jre\bin\java.exe

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

**Android Studio version:**

> Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Canary 9 Build
> #AI-221.5921.22.2211.8881706, built on July 29, 2022 Runtime version: 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866 amd64 VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.

Answer (score 6):

After Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 update, JAVA_HOME path is changed `jre->jbr`. So, you should update **.zshrc** file.

From terminal,

1. Type `open ~/.zshrc` and update the path

`export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home`

2. To apply changes, you need to restart the terminal

Comment: What to do on Windows? I already updated Environment Variables, but seem that Android Studio ignores it

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you need, but you can change the Java JDK that Gradle uses by going to Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle and change the Gradle JDK settings.

You can also change the JAVA_HOME environment variable (not sure if name is the same on different OS) or "changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`."